# Power out during software-installation from usb to external hard drive

Tags: grub2, usb

And now trying to boot brings up gnu grub... i have no idea what to do.

Comment: We will need more information like which version Ubuntu were you installing, how far did the installation get, and what error messages you get when you try to bring up grub.  See https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Because the power went out during the OS installation there's no way to get installed software on the external hard drive back the way it was. Your best option is to start over and reinstall Ubuntu on the external hard drive. The Ubuntu live USB has GParted partition editor built-in which can be run when trying Ubuntu in a live session, but in most cases it is easier in to set the Ubuntu partition(s) from the Ubuntu installer.